# how to select all user ids in the comments of some post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, comments, uid

I need to select all user_ids who leave comment on some post. Is there fql to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ - using an access token for a user who's able to see the post you can retrieve the list of likes and comments on that post.